# Picasso flowchart on Android

Tags: android, picasso, flowchart

Is there a flowchart or documentation available that describes process flow of how [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/) fetches images?

If I have something simple like:

```
Picasso.with(context)
.load(url)
.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_contact_picture)
.error(R.drawable.ic_contact_picture)
.into(imageView);
```

how would I know whether image would be loaded from cache or would it be refetched from url?

Like whether it first checks for memory cache, then disk cache or HTTP client cache control, when does it handle networkpolicy, memorypolicy parameters, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like

```
 Picasso.with(context).setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
 Picasso.with(context).setLoggingEnabled(true);
```

can be close to what you are looking for.